# Order of data and end event of http.createServer

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const server = http.createServer(async (request, response) => {
  
  if (request.method === "POST") {
    var data = "";
    request
      .on("data", async (chunk) => {
        console.log("1");
        data += chunk;

        console.log("2");
        await connection.query({sql query});
        console.log("3");

      
      })
      .on("end", async () => {
        console.log("4");   
      });
  }
}
```

result below

> 1
> 4
> 2
> 3

Do you know how to process synchronously and make result order 1 2 3 4?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it synchronously, why add async keyword. And besides, I preferably would go with the modern day servers and use the express package for this. Use this link: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html